# A 301 Redirect Priority?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm using this Regex expression in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)?$ /bas/blog/$4 [R=301,L]
```

However, due to some limitations, mainly the lack of a date, Posts are labeled as "Post, post-2 etc."

I tried the standard 301 with the format in the experession, the redirect rule took priority over it.

Is there a !important tag of some sort that I can assign it to take priority over the regex expression?

Basically, I want to do

```
Redirect 301 /blog/2008/08/22/fridays-fact http://www.example.com/bas/blog/fridays-fact-11/
```

Answer (score 0):

Ordering of rules is important. Keep specific URL matching rules first and more generic ones later.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/2008/08/22/fridays-fact /bas/blog/fridays-fact-11/ [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)?$ /bas/blog/$4 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Ah. Alright, Let me take a crack at it, I'll let you know if it works. I was thinking in terms of css, lower is higher priority.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you have any doubt / query.